# No module named 'gunicorn'

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to serve Flask with gunicorn and nginx
Here is my systemd unit configuration file

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve odooErp
After=network.target

[Service]
User=tito
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/tito/peg/odoo_api/peg_api
Environment="PATH=/home/tito/peg/odoo_api/peg_api/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/tito/peg/odoo_api/peg_api/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:odooErp.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start the service, I run into the following error despite having installed gunicorn using pip

```
[0;1;31m●[0m odooErp.service - Gunicorn instance to serve productionOdoo
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/odooErp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: [0;1;31mfailed[0m (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-08-18 05:33:23 UTC; 1min 0s ago
 Main PID: 18305 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 43ms

Aug 18 05:33:23 peg-test-01 systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance to serve odooErp.
Aug 18 05:33:23 peg-test-01 gunicorn[18305]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 18 05:33:23 peg-test-01 gunicorn[18305]:   File "/home/tito/peg/odoo_api/peg_api/env/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
Aug 18 05:33:23 peg-test-01 gunicorn[18305]:     from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
Aug 18 05:33:23 peg-test-01 gunicorn[18305]: ImportError: No module named 'gunicorn'
Aug 18 05:33:23 peg-test-01 systemd[1]: [0;1;39modooErp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE[0m
Aug 18 05:33:23 peg-test-01 systemd[1]: [0;1;39modooErp.service: Unit entered failed state.[0m
Aug 18 05:33:23 peg-test-01 systemd[1]: [0;1;39modooErp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.[0m
```

Comment: please cross check whether gunicorn is installed in your env or not

Answer (score 0):

this is probably because the module is not in correct path

if you are on windows you can set the path as follows in your enviroment :
search this pc > properties > advanced system setting in the left corner > enviromental variable in bottom right corner > in the user varible click PATH then new  and set the path

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there can be some confusion if you are running multiple versions of Python; simply running pip will install a module for one version and not another. I usually prefer running ' -m pip install gunicorn'